# How to mock the ApplicationContext in companion object in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Help test a function that calls a class method.
There is a class whose field is initialized with a chain of methods appContext().getBean().

```
class ClassA {
    private val employeeApi: EmployeeApi= appContext().getBean()
    fun execute(): List<Employee> {
        return employeeApi.method()
    }
}
```

and for example there is a function for calls to class methods.

```
    fun methodForTesting(params: ClassA .() -> Unit): List<Employee> {
         return ClassA().apply(params).execute()
    }
```

This function needs to be tested. How to do it?

1. Open access to the method in the file using
   mockkStatic("com.company.MyFile")
2. Create a list of workers who need to be returned
3. Create a method stub
4. Calling the method
5. Checking data

@Test

```
fun `methodForTesting mockk`() {
    mockkStatic("com.company.MyFile")
    val classA : ClassA= Mockito.mock(ClassA::class.java)
    val listEmployee: List<Employee>  = listOf(Employee("Ivan"))
    Mockito.`when`(classA.execute()).thenReturn(listEmployee)

    val list : List<Employee> = methodForTesting(allAny())

    Assertions.assertThat(list).isEqualTo(listEmployee)
}
```

If I write like this, then an error occurs. How can the solution be finalized?

**Error:**
*kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property FIELD has not been initialized
at Mockito.`when`(classA.execute()).thenReturn(listEmployee) <-- HERE*

```
Configuration
EnableConfigurationProperties(HurmaProperties::class)
class AppConfig : ApplicationContextAware {
    private var applicationContext: ApplicationContext? = null

    override fun setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext
        appCtx = applicationContext
    }

    @Bean
    fun restTemplateBuilder(): RestTemplateBuilder = RestTemplateBuilder()

    @Bean
    fun restTemplate(builder: RestTemplateBuilder): RestTemplate =
        builder.build()

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        lateinit var appCtx: ApplicationContext
            private set
    }
}

fun appContext() = AppConfig.appCtx
```

Comment: What's your reason to be using ApplicationContext.getBean()? This is very much non-standard, and I genuinely can't think of a reason to do so instead of using the regular autowiring injections of spring. If you use the default injection way you can just provide custom Beans in your tests so they are injected automatically, without the need to mock a single thing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
If you call getBean() from the ApplicationContext, and you need to test some method, then do this:

```
var employeeApi = mock<EmployeeApi>()
every { appContext().getBean<EmployeeApi>() } returns employeeApi
every { employeeApi.method() } returns listEmployee

val resultList: List<Employee> = methodForTesting();
```